# DataBase for scheduling notification (maybe store in RAM - radis, memcashedb)

Tags: database, notifications, redis, scheduling, memcachedb

I have a lot of data types - datetime, e-mail, data - for sending notification.

If I use the normal database, I need to poll the database by surveying every second.

Please, help me with choice of architecture.

I want store this data in RAM - maybe redis or memcashedb

Comment: Hi, a lot is 'how many' ? With a sql database properly configured, with the right index set, you can handle a lot of records in no time. Are they many relationships between the data ? Could you cache them ?

Comment: I want store this data in RAM (maybe redis or memcashdb - but don't know how)

Comment: Mysql has memory tables. You need to store data on another table before using it, since memory table will be wiped of the memory when the server reboot. Again, with the current information, it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rabbitmq - is open source message broker software (i.e., message-oriented middleware) that implements the Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) standard